# GHC type functions and scoped type variables

Tags: haskell

Consider the following, which is written in a context with ScopedTypeVariables:

```
    defaultGetRestView :: forall view master .
                       ( PersistEntity (PersistentView master view)
                       , PersistStore (YesodPersistBackend master (HandlerT master IO))
                       , MonadTrans (YesodPersistBackend master), YesodPersist master
                       , PersistMonadBackend (YesodPersistBackend master (HandlerT master IO))
                         ~ PersistEntityBackend (PersistentView master view)
                       ) => Key (PersistentView master view) -> HandlerT master IO view

    defaultGetRestView key = ((runDB $ get404 key) :: HandlerT master IO (PersistentView master view))
                         >>= (return . (view :: PersistentView master view -> view))
```

I am having a type error I don't understand.  I am explicitly declaring that the 'view' function that I'm calling is the one that applies to (PersistentView master view):

```
 NB: `PersistentView' is a type function, and may not be injective
  The type variable `master0' is ambiguous
  Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  Expected type: PersistentView master view -> view
    Actual type: PersistentView master0 view -> view
  In the second argument of `(.)', namely
    `(view :: PersistentView master view -> view)'
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this to an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "may not be injective" is the key part of the error. That is, we may have the equality

```
PersistentView master view ~ PersistentView master0 view
```

where `master` differs from `master0`. Because of this non-injectivity, writing `view :: PersistentView master view -> view` fixes the type variable used as a return type (`view`) but it does not fix the `master` type variable, which remains ambiguous.

The type for the view function looks inherently ambiguous, in that it allows no way to fix the value of the `master` type variable. Usually, an extra dummy argument is used for this, as in:

```
view :: master -> PersistentView master view -> view
view _unused persistentView = ...
```

Then `view (undefined::master) pv` would let one to choose the type at which to evaluate `view`.

Comment: But why aren't the scoped type variables enough to fix them?  In particular, the (runDB $ get404 key) line is set to pass in a (PersistentValue master view) to a the 'view' function, which expects a (PersistentValue master view).  And both of those master variables are 'the same type'.  I don't see why GHC is inventing a master0.

Comment: Because the type signature fixes the value of `PersistentView master view -> view`. Since `(->)` is injective (it is a type constructor, not a type family) this fixes the type `view` and the type `PersistentValue master view`. This however is not enough to deduce what `master` should be. I'll update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I also found that setting a FunctionalDependency view -> master resolved the problem, once I grokked why I needed a proxy/dummy.  (Just as an experiment, and for our information, I guess.  I prefer proxies)

Comment: Since you are using type families, I would stick to those instead of FunDeps. That is, I would just add another `Master view` type family and remove the `master` argument from the `PersistentView` type family. This is a matter of preference though -- I tend to use either FunDeps or TypeFamilies but not both.

Comment: Now that refactoring is actually not possible here -- I need both the master and view in the type class definition, so all the type families defined in its scope need both arguments.  I already have data Proxy a = Proxy in scope, so I'll adapt (undefined :: master) to (Proxy :: Proxy master).